# How do I detect a custom event in Angular 2 without using a template?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 project where I am dynamically generating child components and I want to listen to a custom event that is dispatched by that component.

This is my parent component that generates the component and listens for events

```
 var cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);

// PROPERLY DETECTS EVENT 
cmpRef.instance.self.nativeElement.addEventListener('click',this.onEventFired);

// DOESN'T DETECT EVENT
cmpRef.instance.self.nativeElement.addEventListener('isLoaded',this.onEventFired);

// call this method to fire the event
(cmpRef.instance as ChildComponent).load();
```

And this is my ChildComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit,ChangeDetectorRef, Output,EventEmitter,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '  <p>child component- click on text to fire event!</p>'

})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


  @Output('isLoaded') isLoaded:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(public self:ElementRef)
  {
    console.log('ChildComponent Created')
  }

  public load()
  {
    console.log('load method called.... dispatching event')
     this.isLoaded.next(true);
  }
}
```

I need to be able to listen to the events that are being dispatched but for my purposes, I cannot use the template and want to listen directly from my typescript. I have successfully done this with a "click" event but my custom events get dispatched but never gets detected.

I have attached a plunker to show my use case

https://plnkr.co/edit/GGqhRu8pT6Ymz2Bg7oSE?p=preview

Comment: That's not how it's supposed to work, if you want to subscribe to your `isLoaded` event just cast that component created by the factory and subscribe to `isLoaded`, `(<ChildComponent>cmpRef).isLoaded.subscribe(() => your code);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how it's supposed to work, if you want to subscribe to your `isLoaded` event just cast that component created by the factory and subscribe to `isLoaded` event.

Just change your:

```
// DOESN'T DETECT EVENT
cmpRef.instance.self.nativeElement.addEventListener('isLoaded',this.onEventFired);
```

For:

```
// DOESN'T DETECT EVENT
(<ChildComponent>cmpRef.instance).isLoaded.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Has been loaded");
});
```

First case worked because that is a native event of the host.

Comment: Excellent, remember to mark the answer as the solution!